# rails nested attributes form repeating to the count of records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a straightforward simple requirement.
`Donations` are children of `Church`.

church - model

```
  class Church < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :user, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'user_id'

     has_many :donations

     accepts_nested_attributes_for :donations

    end
```

church - controller

```
  class ChurchesController < ApplicationController
       def show
        #  @church = Church.friendly.find(params[:id])
           @church = Church.find(params[:id])
         donations =  @church.donations.build
       end
```

donation - model

```
class Donation < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :church, :class_name => 'Church', :foreign_key => 'church_id'

end
```

Here is the issue.What i have in view/churches/show.erb

```
    <%= form_for(@church ,url: church_path(@church),  html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
        <%= f.fields_for :donations do |d| %>
<div class="content">...</div>

      <% end %>    
      <% end %>
```

Now my trouble is the div.content is repeating to 'n' number of donation records saved. Kindly help

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of that?

Comment: If you don't want that, why don't you just up your div.content outside the fields_for block ?

Comment: but i need to save the model data the actual form would look like

<%= form_for(@church ,url: church_path(@church),  html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>

        <%= f.fields_for :donations do |d| %>

 <%= d.text_field :name, :placeholder => "Name on the card", :class => "form-control", :required => true%>

Answer (score 1):

ah found out the solution. <%= f.fields_for :donations, `Donation.new`  do |d| %>

Without Donation.new it was simply displaying the existing records along with a new form.